# Delphi FMX TListViewItem to set Visible:=false

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tlistview

I fill programmatically DinamycAppearance `TListview`. There I have a TextButton, which sometimes I want to set `Visible:=false`.

```
li := ListView.Items.Add;
```

I tried these solutions, but neither works correctly:

```
li.Objects.ObjectByName('ButtonSelect').Visible := false;
li.View.FindDrawable('ButtonSelect').Visible := false;
```

I also tried to Destroy or Free this Object, but there I got errors.

Additionally sometimes it works, but just on the second buildup, but when I resize the Form, the ListView also forgets the visibility setup.

Do you have working solutions for this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show the minimal **but complete and compilable** code with which we can reproduce the problem, according to [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]. The previous link goes to the help pages of Stack Overflow. There are important information regarding asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a Dynamic Listview item and you want to change the appearance of objects inside the items you need to do it under the `OnUpdateObjects` event of the listview.

Like so:

```pascal
procedure TForm2.lv1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
  if SomeCondition then // SomeCondition is an example
    AItem.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemTextButton>('ButtonSelect').Visible := False;
end;
```

Comment: When I use UpdateObjects event , I cannot add Header or Footer on to ListView, do you have any idea how can I overcome this issue ? ( I use Delphi 11.2) Thanks.

Comment: You are not supposed to add headers or footers under the UpdateObjects event.

Comment: No i didnt , i just meant by adding header or footer in a normal way. But later i found out how to overco.e the issue as  i need to check drawables i  updateojects events if they are nil.